# Why React needs webpack-dev-server to run?

Tags: reactjs, webpack, webpack-dev-server

I'm new to React and I followed [Facebook's Installation](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/installation.html) (Create a New App).

So every time I need to run the app, it needs to start a server. When I try to open the build version in chrome( opening HTML directly ), nothing gets displayed.

Then I tried to setup React environment myself from scratch using [codecademy](https://www.codecademy.com/articles/react-setup-i) tutorial. Here, after I build the project, I can directly open the HTML in chrome and the contents are displayed.

**My question is:**

Why webpage doesn't get displayed in the 1st method but 2nd method runs without starting server?

---

**Edit**:

**package.json** for 2nd method:

```
{
  "name": "practice",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
    "build": "webpack",
    "start": "webpack-dev-server"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "react": "^15.6.1",
    "react-dom": "^15.6.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-core": "^6.26.0",
    "babel-loader": "^7.1.2",
    "babel-preset-react": "^6.24.1",
    "html-webpack-plugin": "^2.30.1",
    "webpack": "^3.6.0",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^2.8.2"
  }
}
```

**webpack.config.js**:

```
var HTMLWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');
var HTMLWebpackPluginConfig = new HTMLWebpackPlugin({
  template: __dirname + '/app/index.html',
  filename: 'index.html',
  inject: 'body'
});

module.exports = {
  entry: __dirname + '/app/index.js',
  module: {
    loaders: [
      {
        test: /\.js$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        loader: 'babel-loader'
      }
    ]
  },
  output: {
    filename: 'transformed.js',
    path: __dirname + '/build'
  },
  plugins: [HTMLWebpackPluginConfig]
};
```

Comment: Simple answer.. determine why you run `npm run build` in your codeacademy and what it does. you should be able to figure this out. If you still have questions after reading that, ping back

Comment: @Panther In my package.json, build script is `webpack` and start script is `webpack-dev-server`. So, in my 2nd method, im just calling `webpack` to call the loader. Im not calling `start` to start the server. I edited my question with package.json.

Comment: What i mean is in `webpack` actually transpiles(using babel), uglifies and builds your `build/dist` folder. So opening index file from them show you the content as all the required js/css are present. While using `dev-server` no acutal files are generated. The required js/css are mostly server from in-meory file system.

Comment: In your `create-react-app` method if you use `npm run build` and then open the index from `build` directory you should see same behaviour for both tutorials.

Comment: @Panther It didn't work. As the answer stated below, the problem is with path. I tried with my 2nd method as he/she mentioned( changing path to my `.js` file )  and it worked and I understood what is wrong.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem is: **path to the other files in the HTML**.

When the `webpack-dev-server` is run from the directory, it assumes it is the root of the server.

So, if you open your app's HTML(`build/index.html`) created with Facebook tutorial, you can see that the path to other files are given as absolute path but not as a relative path.

Like in HTML you can see `/static/pathToFile` but not `./static/pathToFile`.

[image]

So, according to your 2nd method, try to give the path to `transformed.js` as `/transformed.js` in your HTML. It doesn't display anything. But if you run `npm run start` and then open your localhost with given port number(just like in the 1st method). Now you can see your React app.

**Opinion**: Always try to setup your environment by yourself from scratch. Don't try easy to setup methods like Facebook's "create new app". Instead try Facebook's "Adding React to an Existing Application". You can learn how things actually work, like today.

**Tip**:

Try to debug the app always in your web browser!

For example, open your 1st method HTML in your chrome and open developer tools.

Head over to the network tab and reload.
[image]

Hover-over the failed file to see what is the error. You can see `ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND`.

Click on it to see return status, url requested etc.

[image]

Hope it helps!

Comment: Thanks for the  explanation and tip!