# React: How can I show an already existing image in react update form and then show the new one once a new image is uploaded?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-router, jsx

hey guys i am learning react js and I have an update form to update book info. I am using django rest api for endpoints. I have a working form where I can upload files and do all those stuffs but I am not able to show the image which is already there in the template, Here I have a book cover image, which is already there in the database, it should be showing in the front-end and when I change the image, the new one should show, how can I add that feature here, I tried `<img src={formData.book_cover}` and consoling out this is showing the url, but the image isn't getting displayed.

From the network tab,
The problem I think is

`Request URL:http://localhost:3000/media/book/book_sample/pride_in_nat.png`

request url since the image gets displayed if the url is `localhost:8000` instead of `localhost:3000` as it is where the django server backend runs. So, how can I change that?

This is the code.

```
import React from "react";

function BookInfoForm() {

  const initialFormData = Object.freeze({
  id: '',
  book_cover: '',
  book_name: '',
  book_summary: '',
});

const [formData, updateFormData] = useState(initialFormData);
const [image, setImage] = useState(null);
const { register, handleSubmit, control, errors } = useForm();

useEffect(() => {
  axiosInstance.get('api/books/info/update/').then((res) => {
    updateFormData({
              ...formData,
      ['book_cover']: res.data.book_cover,
      ['book_name']: res.data.book_name,
      ['book_summary']: res.data.book_summary,
    });
  });
  }, [updateFormData]);

  const handleChange = (e) => {
    if (e.target.name === 'image') {
        setImage({
            image: e.target.files,
        });
        // console.log(e.target.files);
    } 
    updateFormData({
        ...formData,         
  // Trimming any whitespace
      [e.target.name]: e.target.value
    });
};

const onSubmit = (data) =>{
  let formData = new FormData();

  formData.append('user', user.id),
  formData.append('book_cover', data.image[0]),
  formData.append('book_name', data.book_name),
  formData.append('book_summary', data.book_summary),

  axiosInstance.put('api/books/info/update/', formData),
}

return (
  <>
    <form className={classes.form} noValidate onSubmit={handleSubmit(onSubmit)}>
      <Grid container spacing={2}>
            <Grid item xs={6}>
                {/* Show existing book cover and change when new one is uploaded */}
                <img src={formData.store_logo} alt="" />
                <label htmlFor="book-cover">
                    <input
                    accept="image/*"
                    className={classes.input}
                    id="book-cover"
                    onChange={handleChange}
                    name="image"
                    type="file"
                    ref={register}
                />
                    Book Cover
                    <IconButton color="primary" component="span">
                        <PhotoCamera />
                    </IconButton>
                </label>
            </Grid>

            <Grid item xs={12}>
                <TextField
                    variant="outlined"
                    required
                    fullWidth
                    id="book_name"
                    label="Book Name"
                    name="book_name"
                    autoComplete="book_name"
                    value={formData.book_name}
                    onChange={handleChange}
                    inputRef={register({maxLength: 30})}
                    rows={1}
                />
            </Grid>

            <Grid item xs={12}>
                <TextField
                    variant="outlined"
                    required
                    fullWidth
                    id="book_summary"
                    label="Book Summary"
                    name="book_summary"
                    autoComplete="book_summary"
                    value={formData.book_summary}
                    onChange={handleChange}
                    inputRef={register({maxLength: 1000})}
                    multiline
                    rows={3}
                />
            </Grid>
          </Grid>

          <Button
            type="submit"
            fullWidth
            variant="contained"
            color="primary"
            className={classes.submit}
          >
            Update
        </Button>

      </form>
  </>
)
}
```

Comment: What is the network tab showing about your image request?

Comment: Hey, thanks for the response, I checked the network tab and the file is showing, but when I click , it shows a blank page.
The problem I think is `Request URL: http://localhost:3000/media/book/book_sample/pride_in_nat.png` this as the image shows if the url is localhost:8000 as it is where the django server backend runs. So, how to change that?

Comment: And what part of the URL are you storing in your database? Is it `http://localhost:3000/media/book/book_sample/pride_in_nat.png` or `pride_in_nat.png` or something else?

Comment: I am sorry, I didn't understand that question. I haven't done any changes in its normal saving behavior,

Comment: In the database the link is `book/book_sample/pride_in_nat.png `

Comment: I can't see your `img` tag in the above code. Can you post it too? If you are following any tutorial or pulled a code from public GitHub repo, then provide the link.

Comment: I have updated the code with `img` tag, and I have searched many questions in SO to finish this one, I haven't followed any tutorial.

Thanks

Comment: Is your react app running on `localhost:3000`?

Comment: Yes, it is in `localhost:3000`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might want to take a look at one of my answers on [Why React needs webpack-dev-server to run?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46342463/4859791)

As your frontend is running at `localhost:3000` and you are providing a relative path to the `img` tag, the browser is assuming that the image is at `localhost:3000`.

Whenever your backend host is different than the frontend host, you have to provide a complete URL to the resource i.e., **origin(`http://localhost:8000`) + path to the resource(`/book/book_sample/pride_in_nat.png`)**

As you are storing the **path to the resource** in your database, just append the **origin** while giving it to the `img` tag.

```
<img src={`http://localhost:8000/${formData.store_logo}`} />
```

---

### Suggestion

A better approach is to use `.env` files and load them according to your `development` or `production` environment

```
<img src={`${process.env.IMAGE_STORE_ORIGIN}${formData.store_logo}`} />
```

And in your `.env` file or `.env.development` file, you can add the entry for where your images are stored

In your `.env` file:

```
IMAGE_STORE_ORIGIN=http://localhost:8000/
```

So, when you want to change your backend server origin, you can just change it in one location and it is used inside your entire app instead of changing it manually every time you want to use a new server address.

Take a look at [dotenv](https://www.npmjs.com/package/dotenv) and [dotenv-expand](https://www.npmjs.com/package/dotenv-expand)

I hope this should clarify your "why" and "what".

Comment: Thank you for the wonderful explanation and the given answer, I have a doubt regarding `.env ` file. Should I create this file in public or in the src folder?

Comment: @Danny It should be present at the root of your project directory i.e., at the location where your `package.json` is present.

Comment: Oh.but I don't have it, i have 3 files `package.json`, `package-lock.json` and `gitignore`. Am I missing something?

Comment: @Danny The suggestion part is just a common pattern usually used in production level projects. You don't have to create `.env` file to make it work for you now. You can just follow the part above the suggestion to make it work

Comment: Oh. okay
Thank you! it worked now. Thanks again for the explanation and time. :)

Answer (score 0):

I would advise this as being the best solution and I highly would recommend this even though I have not worked heavily with Django.

I know with Django you can store files in media files as configured in your **settings.py**, as good and convenient that is I guess but the best solution in my understanding for managing files is dealing with a 3rd party like cloudinary(Very common when working with Node using 3rd party software's to manage files)

**So the flow behind:**

- Make an account on cloudinary(Do not worry it's completely free but can upgrade)
- When you want to save a file to DB you first interact with cloudinary with Django.
- Once Django is done cloudinary Api will bring back a url of your image.
- Then what you only have to do now is now save that link given in your database

**Now with your Django Model**

- In the place where you had **image** as a "FileField" now you can safely convert to "CharField" or whatever that means text/string in django kind of forgot
- Then now in your React app that should work

**Cloudinary SDK docs for Django**

https://cloudinary.com/documentation/django_integration

**You can also look up some example on YouTube for clarity if docs are not clear**

https://youtu.be/1T6G7Znrbfg

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion, but here I am looking to solve and learn this problem which I faced. surely, will try to do that with coloudinary too. Thanks for the info.